Getting tikz adjacent nodes with overlapping edges
I want a 9 (across) x 1 (down) grid with the labels as given below such that the right edge of box i and the left edge of box i+1 overlay each other. That is, if we assume that all box lines are 1 pixel thick, the shared box edges should have a combined width of 1 pixel (not 2 pixels).
Given this complete example:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  font=\ttfamily\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont,
  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
]

\node[circle]              (a00) {\textcolor{black}{[0][0]}};
\node[circle,right of=a00] (a01) {\textcolor{black}{[0][1]}};
\node[circle,right of=a01] (a02) {\textcolor{black}{[0][2]}};

\node[circle,right of=a02] (a10) {\textcolor{black}{[1][0]}};
\node[circle,right of=a10] (a11) {\textcolor{black}{[1][1]}};
\node[circle,right of=a11] (a12) {\textcolor{black}{[1][2]}};

\node[circle,right of=a12] (a20) {\textcolor{black}{[2][0]}};
\node[circle,right of=a20] (a21) {\textcolor{black}{[2][1]}};
\node[circle,right of=a21] (a22) {\textcolor{black}{[2][2]}};

\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a00)] {};
\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a01)] {};
\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a02)] {};

\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a10)] {};
\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a11)] {};
\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a12)] {};

\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a20)] {};
\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a21)] {};
\node [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,fit=(a22)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

it looks like the left edge of box i+1 is to the left of the right edge of box i, so, they overlap too much.
How can I fix this to get what I want as initially described?

FYI, I'm using this answer to get squares.

I reduced the font size to 7.75. It seems OK but I don't know why is this?

Yes, that does seem to work, but I would think it should work regardless of the font size.

First, neither LaTeX nor TikZ use pixels for anything.  By using fit, you are basing the spacing on the size of the contents.  Also, lines are drawn half inside and half outside the shape.  I got pretty good results using outer sep=-0.47pt.

The distance from (a00.east) to (a01.west) is -0.92079pt (with outer sep=0pt).

You can also use right=0pt] at(a00.east).  This is why I never use fit or positioning.

off-topic: use the positioning library's updated syntax.

I found a different way to describe the rectangles. The size of the font is affected the size of the rectangles. With my code, you can adjust the rectangle's sizes with boxwidth and boxheight parameters. The code is below:
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  font=\ttfamily\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont,
  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
]
    % Define the box width and height
    \def\boxwidth{1}
    \def\boxheight{1}

    % Draw the boxes
    \foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} {
        \draw[gray,very thin] (\i*\boxwidth, 0) rectangle ({(\i+1)*\boxwidth}, \boxheight);
        % Label the boxes
        \node (\i) at (\i*\boxwidth + 0.5*\boxwidth, 0.5*\boxheight) {};
    }

   \foreach \i in {0, 1, 2}{
   \node at(\i){[0][\i]};}
   \foreach \ii/\i in {0/3, 1/4, 2/5}{
   \node at(\i){[1][\ii]};}
   \foreach \ii/\i in {0/6, 1/7, 2/8}{
   \node at(\i){[2][\ii]};}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Yeah that works. I tweaked it a bit to combine the \node and rectangle in the first \foreach. The boxwidth and boxheight don't seem to be necessary: \node (\i) at (\i,0) [rectangle,draw,gray,very thin,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] {};. Separate tweak: I added \! in ]\![ to kern them a bit better. Though I'm still curious why the original didn't work.

OK. That is up to you.

\draw[draw=gray] (\i*\boxwidth, 0) rectangle node {[…][…]} +(\boxwidth, \boxheight); will place the nodes in the middle of the rectangle without making the text gray. You can use two nested loops, each from 0 to 2, each for one of the two [] parameters.

You don't need to use TikZ. Rectangles can be drawn by \hrule, \vrule TeX primitives. For example, with classical pdftex you can do
\def\Grey{\pdfliteral{.5 G}}  \def\Black{\pdfliteral{0 G}}

\def\gframe#1{\Grey 
   \vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule height 2em depth1.3em
      \kern.5pt\Black#1\kern.5pt\Grey\vrule}\hrule}\Black
}

\newcount\numA \newcount\numB

\hbox{\loop
   {\loop
      \gframe{\tt [\the\numA][\the\numB]}\kern-.4pt
      \advance\numB by 1
      \ifnum\numB<3 \repeat
   }%
   \advance\numA by 1
   \ifnum\numA<3 \repeat
}

\bye

and with OpTeX:
\def\gframe#1{{\Grey \frame{\vrule height2em depth1.3em width0pt\Black #1}}}

\hbox{\fornum 0..2 \do{\fornum 0..2\do{\gframe{\tt [#1][##1]}\kern-.4pt}}}

\bye

The overlapping is done by \kern-.4pt in both cases because default line thickness in TeX is 0.4pt.

Here's a better way to produce squares with TikZ.
The positioning library's right=of … is used which places the nodes with the specified node distance between each other. Both the node distance as well as the outer seps are set to zero so that the paths of the nodes align. Alternatively, node distance = -.5\pgflinewidth and the default outer sep of .5\pgflinewidth can be used as well, if you want to draw edges to these nodes as well.
Code
%\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  square/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    minimum size={
      max(2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})+\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox,
          2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})+\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox+\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox)}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  node distance=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt,
  font=\ttfamily\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont,
  start chain=going right]
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 2}
  \foreach \j in {0, ..., 2}
    \node[square, draw=gray, on chain] {[\i][\j]};
\end{document}

Output

